# Python group similar file name from glob list and append

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, glob

Assume using glob, we read a folder which contains several csv files such as:

```
/C/share\AA_12345_1.csv 

/C/share\AA_12345_2.csv

/C/share\AA_12345_3.csv

/C/share\BB_13_1.csv

/C/share\BB_13_2.csv
```

The goal is to append the csv files based on the similar filename group, example append

```
/C/share\AA_12345_1.csv

...

/C/share\AA_12345_3.csv
```

as one dataframe of `/C/share\AA_12345`

```
/C/share\BB_13_1.csv

/C/share\BB_13_2.csv
```

also as one dataframe of `/C/share\BB_13`

My current approach is using

```
res = [list(i) for j, i in groupby(lof,
          lambda a:a.partition('\.*_\d*_?[0-9]_*(?=_)')[0])]
```

to get group of `[[/C/share\AA_12345_1.csv,/C/share\AA_12345_2.csv , /C/share\AA_12345_3.csv ]`,`[/C/share\BB_13_1.csv,/C/share\BB_13_2.csv]]`
and then for each group read the csv and append.

However the result is still one biglist `[/C/share\AA_12345_1.csv,...,/C/share\BB_13_2.csv]`

Any idea/pointer on how to move forward?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my different approach to get group of similar file:

```
key_func = lambda x : re.search(r"\w*\D_\d*",x).group()

res = [list(j) for i, j  in itertools.groupby(d, key_func)] #d contains list of csv files
for i in res:
    print(i)
```